# Conditional expected value of die roll

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

I need some help in solving the following problem.
We roll a fair die repeatedly until see the number $6$. Let $X$ be a random variable is a number of times we roll the die. Let $A$ be the event "The results of all rolls are even numbers". What is the value of $\mathbb{E}(X|A)$?

Comment: See if this helps you: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-expected-number-of-rolls-of-a-fair-six-sided-die-to-get-a-6-given-that-all-rolls-leading-up-to-that-6-are-even-numbered

Comment: This problem is discussed at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2463768/understanding-the-math-behind-elchanan-mossel-s-dice-paradox

Comment: thanks guys. I got it